# Create environment from file without additional dependencies

Tags: python, anaconda

Is there a way to create the conda environment from a file without installing packages not listed in dependencies?

This is my environment file:

```
name: sample_env
channels:
- anaconda
- conda-forge
- defaults
dependencies:
- _tflow_select=2.1.0
- absl-py=0.7.1
- astor=0.7.1
- binutils_impl_linux-64=2.31.1
- binutils_linux-64=2.31.1
- blas=2.7
- bzip2=1.0.6
- c-ares=1.15.0
- ca-certificates=2019.3.9
- cairo=1.16.0
- certifi=2019.3.9
- cloudpickle=1.2.1
- cudatoolkit=10.0.130
- cudnn=7.6.0
- cupti=10.0.130
- cycler=0.10.0
- cytoolz=0.9.0.1
- dask-core=1.2.2
- dbus=1.13.6
- decorator=4.4.0
- expat=2.2.5
- ffmpeg=4.1.3
- fontconfig=2.13.1
- freetype=2.10.0
- gast=0.2.2
- gcc_impl_linux-64=7.3.0
- gcc_linux-64=7.3.0
- gettext=0.19.8.1
- giflib=5.1.9
- glib=2.58.3
- gmp=6.1.2
- gnutls=3.6.5
- graphite2=1.3.13
- grpcio=1.16.1
- gst-plugins-base=1.14.5
- gstreamer=1.14.5
- gxx_impl_linux-64=7.3.0
- gxx_linux-64=7.3.0
- h5py=2.9.0
- harfbuzz=2.4.0
- hdf5=1.10.4
- icu=58.2
- imageio=2.5.0
- intel-openmp=2019.4
- jasper=1.900.1
- jpeg=9c
- keras=2.2.4
- keras-applications=1.0.8
- keras-preprocessing=1.1.0
- kiwisolver=1.1.0
- lame=3.100
- libblas=3.8.0
- libcblas=3.8.0
- libedit=3.1.20181209
- libffi=3.2.1
- libgcc-ng=9.1.0
- libgfortran-ng=7.3.0
- libgpuarray=0.7.6
- libiconv=1.15
- liblapack=3.8.0
- liblapacke=3.8.0
- libopenblas=0.3.6
- libpng=1.6.37
- libprotobuf=3.8.0
- libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0
- libtiff=4.0.10
- libuuid=2.32.1
- libwebp=1.0.2
- libxcb=1.13
- libxml2=2.9.9
- lz4-c=1.8.3
- mako=1.0.10
- markdown=3.1.1
- markupsafe=1.1.1
- mkl=2019.4
- mkl_fft=1.0.13
- mkl_random=1.0.4
- mock=3.0.5
- ncurses=6.1
- nettle=3.4.1
- networkx=2.3
- numpy=1.16.4
- numpy-base=1.16.4
- olefile=0.46
- openblas=0.3.5
- opencv=4.1.0
- openh264=1.8.0
- openssl=1.1.1b
- pcre=8.41
- pillow=6.0.0
- pip=19.1.1
- pixman=0.34.0
- protobuf=3.8.0
- pthread-stubs=0.4
- pygpu=0.7.6
- pyparsing=2.4.0
- python=3.7.3
- python-dateutil=2.8.0
- pywavelets=1.0.3
- pyyaml=5.1.1
- qt=5.9.7
- readline=7.0
- scikit-image=0.15.0
- scipy=1.3.0
- setuptools=41.0.1
- six=1.12.0
- sqlite=3.28.0
- tensorboard=1.13.1
- tensorflow=1.13.1
- tensorflow-base=1.13.1
- tensorflow-estimator=1.13.0
- tensorflow-gpu=1.13.1
- termcolor=1.1.0
- theano=1.0.4
- tk=8.6.9
- toolz=0.9.0
- tornado=6.0.2
- werkzeug=0.15.4
- wheel=0.33.4
- x264=1!152.20180806
- xorg-kbproto=1.0.7
- xorg-libice=1.0.9
- xorg-libsm=1.2.3
- xorg-libx11=1.6.7
- xorg-libxau=1.0.9
- xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3
- xorg-libxext=1.3.4
- xorg-libxrender=0.9.10
- xorg-renderproto=0.11.1
- xorg-xextproto=7.3.0
- xorg-xproto=7.0.31
- xz=5.2.4
- yaml=0.1.7
- zlib=1.2.11
- zstd=1.4.0
```

My application worked fine with only those packages installed. But when I removed the environment and created a new one, using this file, conda installed a lot of additional dependencies, like PyQt5. Maybe one of the listed packages has such dependency, but I dont want it installed in my environment. Is there a way to achieve that with conda or I have to create a shell script to install all of that one by one with `--no-deps` flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the conda environment and add the dependencies from the environment.yml file to a requirement.txt. Install those packages from requirement.txt to the created environment using conda install command. To implement this, follow the steps below:

1. conda create -n sample_env
2. source activate sample_env
3. conda install --file requirement.txt --no-deps